# Error in Pydantic Validation when a class inherits from another class

Tags: python, validation, inheritance, pydantic

I've defined a class named MetaPersistent:

```
class MetaPersistent(type(BaseModel)):

    Ref: ClassVar[type[RefBase[Self]]]

    Repository: ClassVar[type[RepositoryBase[Self]]]

    def __new__(cls, *args, skip_meta_init=False, **kwargs):
        return super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

    def __init__(self, *args, skip_meta_init=False, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # name, bases, dict = args

        if skip_meta_init is True:
            return

        # Make a repository class for the new persistent class

        rep_bases = tuple(
            {
                getattr(base, "Repository"): None
                for base in self.__mro__
                if hasattr(base, "Repository")
            }.keys()
        )

        rep_cls = type(
            "Repository",
            rep_bases,
            {
                "__module__": self.__module__,
                "__qualname__": f"{self.__qualname__}.Repository",
                "__persistent__": self,
            },
        )

        # Instance the repository
        repository = 
            rep_cls(_english_inflector.tableize(self.__qualname__))

        # Make a reference class for the new persistent class
        ref_bases = tuple(
            {
                getattr(base, "Ref"): None
                for base in self.__mro__
                if hasattr(base, "Ref")
            }.keys()
        )

        ref_cls = type(
            "Ref",
            ref_bases,
            {
                "__module__": self.__module__,
                "__qualname__": f"{self.__qualname__}.Ref",
                "__persistent__": self,
                "__repository__": repository,
            },
        )

        setattr(self, "Repository", rep_cls)
        setattr(self, "Ref", ref_cls)

        setattr(self, "__repository__", repository)
```

From which inherits Persistent:

```
class Persistent(BaseModel, metaclass=MetaPersistent, skip_meta_init=True):
    id: Optional[Id] = Field(None, title="Unique object Id", alias="_id")

    @property
    def ref(self) -> RefBase[Self]:
    return self.Ref(self.id)

    async def store(self) -> RefBase[Self]:
        if self.id:
            await repository_of(self).update_obj(self)
        else:
            await repository_of(self).insert_obj(self)

        return self.ref
```

Then, a class named Vehicle inherites from it:

```
class Vehicle(Persistent):
    tenant_ref: Optional[Tenant.Ref] = None  # Reference to the tenant (default is None)
    loadLimits: float  # Load limits of the vehicle
    startLocation: Location  # Starting location of the vehicle
    endLocation: Location  # Ending location of the vehicle

    class Config:
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True  # Allows arbitrary types
```

The problem arises when I'm instantiating a Vehicle by doing:

```
vehicles = [Vehicle(
    loadLimits=vehicle["loadLimits"],
    startLocation=Location(**vehicle["startLocation"]),
    endLocation=Location(**vehicle["endLocation"])
        ) for vehicle in json_data_vehicles]
```

Pydantic throws:

```
vehicles = [Vehicle(
            ^^^^^^^^
line 164, in __init__
__pydantic_self__.__pydantic_validator__.validate_python(data, 
self_instance=__pydantic_self__)
TypeError: BaseModel.validate() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

On the other side, if Vehicle inherits straight from BaseModel like Vehicle(BaseModel), not problem is found. Guess there are some issues in the way Pydantic validates inheritance, but I'm not able to fix it.

Comment: Could you show the code for `MetaPersistent` metaclass?

Comment: @ Paweł Rubin. Here's the code with the MetaPersistent metaclass.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out that there are some issues between Pydantic v1 and v2. Since some of my imports relied on v1, the code crashed for unknown reasons. I've fixed it by importing all of them from v2, which is the default one:

```
from pydantic.v1 import BaseModel #importing from v1. Code crashes

from pydantic import BaseModel #importing from v2. Code runs ok
```